# CKEditor delete Format combobox

Tags: ckeditor

When I delete the Format combobox in toolbar, CKEditor deletes my own formatting.

I would like to use formatting as separate buttons. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor by default has some filter rules, which prevent of having trash in output HTML.
When you add a plugin, then such plugin usually register set of rules which are necessary for its work. E.g. When you add an `image` plugin then `<img>` tags starts to be allowed in editor contents.

So when you remove `formatting` plugin, then most probably you also remove those filtering rules. That's why your formatting is removed from the editor. You can add your own custom rules with: [extraAllowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent).

I don't know how are you going to add separate buttons with formatting, but in case of creating your own plugin you can also register proper filter rules inside your plugin code.